# Which drivers/utilities should I install for my motherboard?

Tags: drivers, motherboard

I just bought the [Gigabyte B365M DS3H](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/B365M-DS3H-rev-10/support#support-dl-driver) motherboard. It comes with a CD with the label "300 series drivers / utilities" but I don't own a CD reader. In the motherboard [website](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/B365M-DS3H-rev-10/support#support-dl-driver) there are tons of drivers and software. Which ones should I install ? Which ones should I avoid ?. Thanks.

Edit: Using Windows 10

Comment: What OS? If I assume Windows 10, then just use all the default drivers from Windows and and only install any drivers for devices that don't work properly... No need to over complicate it.

Comment: Agreed with @acejavelin.  Don't install ANYTHING except the OS unless you have to in order to get something to work.

Comment: For sure you will need Audio, LAN, VGA.